# Pandas groupby filter only last two rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on pandas manipulation and want to select only the last two rows for each column "B".

## How to do without reset_index and filter (do inside groupby)

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': list('aaabbbbcccc'),
    'B': [0,1,2,5,7,2,1,4,1,0,2],
    'V': range(10,120,10)
})

df
```

## My attempt

```
df.groupby(['A','B'])['V'].sum()
```

## Required output

```
A  B
a  
   1     20
   2     30
b  
   5     40
   7     50
c  
   2    110
   4     80
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `groupby` with the `as_index=False` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.sort_values(['A', 'B']).groupby(['A']).tail(2)
```

Output:

```
    A  B    V
1   a  1   20
2   a  2   30
3   b  5   40
4   b  7   50
10  c  2  110
7   c  4   80
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want to get the rows the highest two B per A.

You can compute a descending [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) per group and keep those ≤ 2.

```
df[df.groupby('A')['B'].rank('first', ascending=False).le(2)]
```

Output:

```
    A  B    V
1   a  1   20
2   a  2   30
3   b  5   40
4   b  7   50
7   c  4   80
10  c  2  110
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.sort_values('B').iloc[-2:,1:]

df.groupby(['A']).apply(function1).droplevel(1)
```

out

```
  B    V
A        
a  1   20
a  2   30
b  5   40
b  7   50
c  2  110
c  4   80
```